# C# WPF Main Window to be always sitting in front of Desktop

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a small WPF application that i would always like to show in front of the desktop however behind all other applications. I have tried a few ways to create this but either the window gets minimized (WindKey + D) or it displays in front of all applications.

Basically I would like to run a label inside the main window. It has a transparent background over the desktop and the message text will change every week. (Safety message for my work place for all users).

```
using System.Windows;



namespace ESLMessage
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    /// 
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        InitialiseScreenSettings();
        this.ShowInTaskbar = false;

    }

    public void InitialiseScreenSettings()
    {

        double screenWidth = System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth;
        double screenHeight = System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight;
        double windowWidth = this.Width;
        double windowHeight = this.Height;
        this.Left = (screenWidth / 2) - (windowWidth / 2);
        this.Top = (screenHeight / 2) - (windowHeight / 2);
        //this.Width = System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth;
        //this.Height = System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight;
        //this.Topmost = true;

        if (!IsVisible)
        {
            Show();
        }

        if (WindowState == WindowState.Minimized)
        {
            WindowState = WindowState.Normal;
        }
        Activate();
        Topmost = true;  // important
        Topmost = false; // important
        Focus();         // important
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code :

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern bool SetWindowPos(
    IntPtr hWnd,
    IntPtr hWndInsertAfter,
    int X,
    int Y,
    int cx,
    int cy,
    uint uFlags);

const UInt32 SWP_NOSIZE = 0x0001;
const UInt32 SWP_NOMOVE = 0x0002;

static readonly IntPtr HWND_BOTTOM = new IntPtr(1);

static void SendWpfWindowBack(Window window)
{
    var hWnd = new WindowInteropHelper(window).Handle;
    SetWindowPos(hWnd, HWND_BOTTOM, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOMOVE);
}
```

Source: http://www.aeroxp.org/board/lofiversion/index.php?t4983.html

**EDIT :**

Sorry. You have to handle the loaded event of the MainWindow and sent it to back.
Try this :

**Codebehind :**

```
private void MainWindow_OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    SendWpfWindowBack(Application.Current.MainWindow);
}
```

**Xaml :**

```
    Loaded="MainWindow_OnLoaded"
```

Still pressing Win+D will hide it. But it is somewhat similar to your requirement. 
If you want to show all your employees a particular message permanently, try consider using a wallpaper. You could set the same wallpaper for everyone and disable the employees from changing it.

Comment: Thanks IDisposable. I tried something similar howevre I'm not sure how to call the SendWpfWindowBack method after InitialiseComponents();. Can you advise?

Comment: Do this : `SendWpfWindowBack(this);` in InitialiseComponents()

Comment: I can still use Windows Key + D to minimize it completely. Also it doesn't go straight to the back when first run. (Shows over Visual Studio). Any ideas?

Comment: I think your requirement is bit different than I expected. Set these properties for your window and check if there is any update. `WindowStyle="None" ResizeMode="NoResize" ShowInTaskbar="False" Topmost="False" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" `

Comment: I had all of those set already. When i run the application, the message displays straight away to the user on the screen. It needs to go back to only being over the desktop image and it staying there. Example here: https://imagebin.ca/v/2oRhbKOQkGYB

Comment: Thanks. That basically works. I might look at putting in something that when the user presses Win + D it populates it the text there. Apart from that, thanks for your help.

Comment: Glad to help. As I said, there would be many limitations for that. But still the basic requirement would work. I had been through a similar scenario and ended up using a wallpaper for all users, which displayed the message.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
private KeyboardFilter kbFilter;

private void MainForm_Activated(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    kbFilter = new KeyboardFilter(new Keys[] 
    { 
        Keys.LWin | Keys.D,
        Keys.RWin | Keys.D,
        Keys.LWin | Keys.X, // if you need
        Keys.RWin | Keys.X, // if you need
        Keys.Alt  | Keys.F4  // if you need
    });
}

private void MainForm_Deactivate(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    kbFilter.Dispose();
}
```

Be sure to use `KeyboardFilter.Dispose()` in the `MainForm_Deactivate` event.

`KeyboardFilter` class was taken from [Here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/72f46c4c-cfba-4535-9376-5c03303e7a59/how-can-i-disable-the-lwin-and-rwin-keyboard-keys?forum=netfxbcl)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.ComponentModel;

class KeyboardFilter : IDisposable
{
    private Keys[] mFilter;
    private IntPtr mHook;
    private readonly LowLevelKeyboardProc mProc;

    public KeyboardFilter(Keys[] keysToFilter)
    {
        // Install hook
        mFilter = keysToFilter;
        ProcessModule mod = Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule;
        mProc = KeyboardProc;   // Avoid garbage collector problems
        mHook = SetWindowsHookEx(13, mProc, GetModuleHandle(mod.ModuleName), 0);
        if (mHook == IntPtr.Zero) throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error(), "Failed to set hook");
    }
    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            // Release hook
            if (mHook != IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                UnhookWindowsHookEx(mHook);
                mHook = IntPtr.Zero;
            }
        }
    }
    ~KeyboardFilter()
    {
        Dispose(false);
    }
    private IntPtr KeyboardProc(int nCode, IntPtr wp, IntPtr lp)
    {
        // Callback, filter key
        if (nCode >= 0)
        {
            KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT info = (KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT)Marshal.PtrToStructure(lp, typeof(KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT));
            foreach (Keys key in mFilter)
                if ((key & Keys.KeyCode) == info.key && CheckModifier(key)) return (IntPtr)1;
        }
        return CallNextHookEx(mHook, nCode, wp, lp);
    }
    private static bool CheckModifier(Keys key)
    {
        // Check if modifier key in required state
        if ((key & Keys.Control) == Keys.Control &&
          GetAsyncKeyState(Keys.LControlKey) == 0 && GetAsyncKeyState(Keys.RControlKey) == 0) return false;
        if ((key & Keys.Shift) == Keys.Shift &&
          GetAsyncKeyState(Keys.LShiftKey) == 0 && GetAsyncKeyState(Keys.RShiftKey) == 0) return false;
        if ((key & Keys.Alt) == Keys.Alt &&
          GetAsyncKeyState(Keys.LMenu) == 0 && GetAsyncKeyState(Keys.RMenu) == 0) return false;
        return true;
    }

    // P/Invoke declarations
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    private struct KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT
    {
        public Keys key;
        public int scanCode;
        public int flags;
        public int time;
        public IntPtr extra;
    }
    private delegate IntPtr LowLevelKeyboardProc(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);
    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr SetWindowsHookEx(int id, LowLevelKeyboardProc callback, IntPtr hMod, uint dwThreadId);
    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern bool UnhookWindowsHookEx(IntPtr hook);
    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr CallNextHookEx(IntPtr hook, int nCode, IntPtr wp, IntPtr lp);
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr GetModuleHandle(string name);
    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    private static extern short GetAsyncKeyState(Keys key);
}
```

[c#](/questions/tagged/c%23)[wpf](/questions/tagged/wpf)

Comment: Thanks Prasad. I am getting a "The name Keys could not be found". I think this is due to me using WPF instead of Windows Forms?